# Running Test Suite from Command Line - MVN test - Says Zero tests ran

Tags: maven, cucumber, rest-assured, test-runner

I have written a test suite to test my api using RestAssured, Cucumber and Java. When I run my tests from the CucumberOptions TestRunner I can see all my 5 test case features running and passing. But I I open a terminal window and navigate the test project and enter the following command (see below) the test results say "Tests run 0".

> mvn test

Below is my pom.xml file:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
      <groupId>Automation101</groupId>
      <artifactId>Automation101APICucumber</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
      <name>Automation101APICucumber</name>
      <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
      <url>http://www.example.com</url>
    
      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
      </properties>
    
      <dependencies>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <!-- -->    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.36</version>
    </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.36</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    
    
      </dependencies>
    
      <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
          <plugins>
            <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
      </build>
    </project>

This i my test runner class:-

package CucumberOptions;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/java/Features",
        glue = {"StepDefinitions"}
)       
public class TestRunner {

}
```

I will also provide a screen shot of my project folder structuring as this may be helpful:-

[image]

Any help to why the output in the command terminal says '0' test ran, would be hugely helpful to me. Thanks

Comment: Where is your test classes? Do those match naming convention that maven-surefire can look for?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was causing the issue. It was because I was using JUnit and TestNG in the same project. I removed all references to TestNG (including the pom.xml file). I then re-ran the test suite from the command line and it now shows 5 tests have been ran.